# Python: IndexError: list index out of range happens in some case only

Tags: python, python-3.x, index-error

I have been making a programme about a tic-tac-toe game which requires two players take turn to input like the coordinate of the board, like `(r1,c1)->(r2,c2)->(r3,c3)-> …`, in which r is the row and c is the column and the board look like

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

The programme I typed:

```
board=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
def show():
    print(str(board[0])+str(board[1])+str(board[2]))
    print(str(board[3])+str(board[4])+str(board[5]))
    print(str(board[6])+str(board[7])+str(board[8]))
def check(char,spot1,spot2,spot3):
    if board[spot1]==char and board[spot2]==char and board[spot3]==char:
        return True
def checkAll(char):
    if check(char,0,1,2):
        return True
    if check(char,3,4,5):
        return True
    if check(char,6,7,8):
        return True
    if check(char,0,3,6):
        return True
    if check(char,1,4,7):
        return True
    if check(char,2,5,8):
        return True
    if check(char,0,4,8):
        return True
    if check(char,2,4,6):
        return True
    else:
        return False
def ChangeSpotInputToAList(spotInput):
    spotafter=[]
    for i in spotInput:
        if i=="(0,0)":
            spotafter.append(0)
        if i=="(0,1)":
            spotafter.append(1)
        if i=="(0,2)":
            spotafter.append(2)
        if i=="(1,0)":
            spotafter.append(3)
        if i=="(1,1)":
            spotafter.append(4)
        if i=="(1,2)":
            spotafter.append(5)
        if i=="(2,0)":
            spotafter.append(6)
        if i=="(2,1)":
            spotafter.append(7)
        if i=="(2,2)":
            spotafter.append(8)
    return spotafter
i=0
spotInput=input().split("->")
spotafter=ChangeSpotInputToAList(spotInput)
for x in spotafter:
    show()
    if spotafter[x]%2==0:
        print("X-->",x)
        spot=x
        i+=1
        char="X"
        board[spot]=char
        if i==9:
            show()
            print("Winner: None")
            break
        if checkAll(char):
            show()
            print("Winner:",char)
            break
    if spotafter[x]%2==1:
        print("O-->",x)
        spot=x
        i+=1
        char="O"
        board[spot]=char
        if i==9:
            show()
            print("Winner: None")
            break
        if checkAll(char):
            show()
            print("Winner:",char)
            break
```

I have tried some input but one of them keeps making an error, which is `(2,2)->(0,0)->(1,1)->(0,2)->(1,0)->(0,1)`, and the programme shows:

```
012
345
678
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "thisishardlol.py", line 55, in <module>
    if spotafter[x]%2==0:
IndexError: list index out of range
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "thisishardlol.py", line 55, in <module>
    if spotafter[x]%2==0:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Does anyone know where am I wrong? Any help would be very greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's run through a scenario:

```
spotInput = input().split("->")
spotafter = ChangeSpotInputToAList(spotInput)
```

If I input `(2,2)->(2,2)` then `spotafter = [8,8]`

Now I enter the for loop:

```
for x in spotafter:
    show()
    if spotafter[x] % 2 == 0:
```

In the first loop, `x = 8` and I'm trying to get `spotafter[8]`, which doesn't exist (`spotafter` only has 2 elements).

I can't help much more since I dont know your goal, but that's why you're getting the IndexError.

Comment: Yes, and as a side note, `for x in y: y[x]` patterns are almost always wrong (especially if used by a beginner). For loops iterate over items, not indices.

Comment: thank you so much, the problem is solved now! I change for x in spotafter: into for x in range(len(spotafter)):